# How to create two shapes inside an item drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a custom layout for a progressbar which consist of small bars depending on the count of steps. A layout can be seen below:
[image: progressbar]
I want to create an item that shows a black bar and a white bar which looks like space in between progresses.

Now, I know its possible to create this with two separate item. But I the item as progress of a progressbar. For example:

```
<!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape 1>
            <shape 2>
        </clip>
    </item>
```

Now, how can I create a custom item that can consist of two shapes inside it?

Comment: use `<layer-list>`

Comment: Create a vector drawable for this image.

Answer (score 0):

**progress.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="3dp"
        android:height="2dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/text_field"
        android:start="@dimen/dimen_5dp" />

    <item
        android:width="3dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/text_field"
        android:end="@dimen/dimen_5dp" />

</layer-list>
```

**text_field.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:startColor="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image: Output]